# How can I finish my code based on the given question and what I have so far

Tags: sql, ms-access

Before I continue I do want to say this is FOR homework for my class. We are using SQL in Microsoft Access. With the transition to online classes because of covid-19 and my professor developing the virus last month we have not have had time to really dive much into how SQL works. I will also provide a picture of the ER Diagram I have of the database to hopefully provide a clear picture of what I'm trying to achieve. https://i.stack.imgur.com/c086p.jpg

Now the question I'm given to solve is this:

3. Retrieve the phone number of the customer(s), who lives in Tyler,  TX, booked two rooms on Jan 1, 2020.

The code I have written so far is as follows

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.Phone_No, CUSTOMER.Address, RESERVATION.Reservation_No, INCLUDES.Check_in, ROOM.Room_No 

FROM CUSTOMER, RESERVATION, INCLUDES, ROOM 

SELECT CUSTOMER.Phone_No, WHERE CUSTOMER.Address = 'Tyler, Tx' AND INCLUDES.Check_in < '12/31/2019' AND INCLUDES.Check_in > '01/01/2020'
```

I'm pretty stuck on where to go now or even if what I have so far will work. Could someone give me a point in the right direction on where I should go now?

Comment: It's kind of unclear how the database schema looks like based on your image. I would expect that "INCLUDES" is the name of an action, but you use it as table name in your query.

Comment: `JOIN`. `JOIN`. `JOIN`

Comment: You can learn a lot of SQL with the Access query builder and switching to SQLView to see what it constructs. You basically need to JOIN tables and apply filter criteria. Cannot have two SELECT clauses like that. Use # to delimit date/time parameters. Visit SQL tutorial sites. Here is one https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: Domin0 you're correct. Im just stressed trying to get this done that I have added a few incorrect things. Thanks for pointing that out. 

June7 I've tried using that site to read through but trying to teach myself as I go is a bit hard. I know I just need to keep working and take a break occasionally to look at it from a fresh perspective. I'll look more into setting up the date and time parameters and how to properly join the tables for them to work the way I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want customer info, use an aggregate query. Each field pulled must be included in GROUP BY clause:
`SELECT Customer.ID, CustomerName, Phone_No FROM Customer INNER JOIN Reservation ON Customer.ID = Reservation.CustomerID WHERE Address = 'Tyler, Tx' AND Check_in BETWEEN #12/31/2019# AND #01/01/2020# GROUP BY Customer.ID, CustomerName, Phone_No HAVING Count(CustomerID) = 2;`

Or take advantage of the power of nested query and IN() function:
`SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Customer.Address = 'Tyler, Tx' AND Customer.ID IN (SELECT CustomerID FROM Reservation WHERE Check_in BETWEEN #12/31/2019# AND #01/01/2020# GROUP BY CustomerID HAVING Count(*) = 2);`

Or use DCount(). However, domain aggregate functions can slow query performance.
`SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Customer.Address = 'Tyler, Tx' AND DCount("*", "Reservation", "Check_in BETWEEN #12/31/2019# AND #01/01/2020# AND CustomerID=" & Customer.ID) = 2;`